# Diablo 2 procuring affixes on mercenaries (hirelings)

Tags: diablo-ii

If I give my mercenary an item that has "Chance to cast" attribute, will it work?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it will work as normal.

See the [ultimate guide to mercs](http://diablo.incgamers.com/forums/showthread.php?306061-Ultimate-Merc-Guide-V3-0) for more tips on mercenaries:

> (2) Most other mods (Crushing Blow, Open Wounds, Chance to Cast on Striking, Faster Cast Rate, Faster Hit Recovery, Increased Attack Speed, etc.) do work for mercs.

Answer (score 1):

They all should work, except the `Peace` runeword's `chance to cast Valkyrie`, because it is bugged. It even works buggy on the player, making spawned Valkyrie despawn, because the server doesn't find a skill point invested (or granted by another item) into Valkyrie skill on player, and Mercenaries can't have their own minions.

I hear the same stuff happens with `Spirit of Barbs`, Druid's summoned creature, charged skill from `Bramble` runeword, but everything else should work.